# Casting from inherited Classes C++

Tags: c++, casting

I have three base Classes **{Player,Weapon,Game}** and one inherited Class Warrior from Player.

I would like to code function **addWizard** using function **addPlayer**.I thought of dymanic casting,but I'm not sure how to start. Any help would be appreciated.

**Notes**:

*Each index in playersArray consists of pointers to class Player.

*If a player's name in a given index i, playersArray[i] equals to empty string, 
    it indicates there's no player yet.

*I added the constructors of each Class Game and Player(the default only) and Wizard.

```
void addWizard(string const& playerName,string const& weaponName,
                       Target target, int hitstrength,int range);

GameStatus Game::addPlayer(const string playerName, const string weaponName,
                               Target target,int hit_strength)
    {   int count=0,place=0;
        if(this->countPlayers()>=maxPlayer)
        {
            throw GameFull();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<maxPlayer;i++)
        {
            if(playersArray[i]->getPlayerName()!="" &&
               playersArray[i]->isPlayer(playerName))
            {
                throw NameAlreadyExists();
            }
            if(playersArray[i]->getPlayerName()==""&& count==0)
            {
                count++;
                place=i;
            }
        }
        Weapon newWeapon(weaponName,target,hit_strength);
        Player newPlayer(playerName,newWeapon);
        *playersArray[place]=newPlayer;
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Classes:

```
class Game {
        int maxPlayers;
        Player **playersArray;
}

class Player {
        string player_name;
        int level;
        int strength;
        Weapon player_weapon; }

//the inherited Class 

class Wizard : public Player {
    int range;
public:
    Wizard();
    Wizard (string const& name, Weapon const& weapon, int range);
}
```

Constructs:

```
Game::Game(int maxPlayer)
: maxPlayer(maxPlayer),playersArray(new Player*[maxPlayer])
{
    for(int i=0;i<maxPlayer;i++)
    {
        playersArray[i]=new Player;
    }
}

Player::Player():
        level(0),life(0),strength(0),place(0),player_name()
{
}

Wizard::Wizard(string const& name, Weapon const& weapon, int range) :
        Player(name,weapon),range(range){
    if (weapon.getTarget() == LIFE){
        throw IllegalWeapon();
    }
    if(range<0)
        throw InvalidParam();
}
```

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a common implementation between those two methods - you need to consider separate this implementation from "addPlayer" method.

Create a function:

```
int FindEmptyPlace(const string& playerName) {
    // logic to find the empty place
    // BTW, you can brake the for loop after you find the place
}
```

Change AddPlayer method to get Player*:

```
GameStatus Game::addPlayer(Player* player, int place);
```

Then implement two methods with different arguments:

```
GameStatus Game::addRegPlayer(const string playerName, const string weaponName,
                           Target target,int hit_strength);
GameStatus Game::addWizard(string const& playerName,string const& weaponName,
                   Target target, int hitstrength,int range);
```

On those two methods - find the empty place and call the new "addPlayer" method to create the weapon and insert the player to the suitable place (you might consider create the weapon within every function and send it as argument to "addPlayer").

Comment: Thank you! So I can use the addPlayer function using this algorithm? or just the methods,my purpose is to use the function addPlayer in AddWizard

Comment: See the another option  I added

Comment: Should I use dymanic cast? or this is enough?
    playersArray[place]=player;

Comment: If your playersArray holds pointers of Player* so a regular assignment will do it. No need of dynamic cast. Basically, when you need to use a dynamic cast - know that something is wrong with your design.

Comment: It gives me this error: undefined reference to `vtable for Wizard'

Comment: I don't know your program, all I can say is - try to debug and check.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not going to write up a bunch of code because I have to be going soon.

But what I see is that your `addPlayer` function should accept a `Player` reference or pointer, or better yet a `std::unique_ptr` instead of constructing a `Player` itself.

Then it would be a simple matter to pass anything that inherits from a `Player` into `addPlayer` to have it added to the game world.

Comment: i think the question was for `addWizard()`